# Facebook allowrequest for unsubscribed friends

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

How I can use

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'Gooby pls'
}, requestCallback);
```

to send a request for my app ONLY to friends that have not received a request yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a database of some kind of who's got requests from who (probably already has), you can use the request dialog's `exclude_ids` field to remove them from the list. Just list the user ids:

```
 FB.ui({
     method: 'apprequests',
     message: 'Gooby pls',
     exclude_ids: ['42'] // add real facebook user ids here
}, requestCallback);
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! Perfect! In this way I can pass an array! :D